# Why c++ source code can call c code without the extern "C"?

Tags: c++, c, linux

Here is a cpp application calling the linux c function. I compiled and run it in linux with g++ 4.7. It works. I am not good at c++. But I heard that you need to declare the 'extern "C"' when you want to call c function from c++ source file. Why this program works ?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    rmdir("t");
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... Because it's done directly in the header files?

Comment: The `<unicode.h>` header file is available for you to read. You will see `extern "C"` in it.

Comment: It needs to be *declared* `extern "C"` (which is done in the header file). You don't need to write it to *call* it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Where is the header file you mentioned located ?

Comment: @JeffLi All system header files should be in `/usr/include` on a POSIX (e.g. Linux, OSX) system.

Comment: I think you meant the `<unistd.h>` header.

Comment: @tangrs Ah yes of course you're right.

Answer (score 5):

The `unistd.h` header file is written to be compatible with C++.  If you look inside it you will find something like:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

...

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
```

If you're on a platform where `unistd.h` is not protected in this manner then you would need to use `extern "C"` around the include.

Comment: I compiled it in ubuntu 13.04. I am afraid I can't find anything you mentioned in /usr/include/unistd.h .

Comment: It will likely include another source file which does that so that the logic doesn't have to be repeated in every header

Comment: @JeffLi but it starts with __BEGIN_DECL, which is `#define __BEGIN_DECL extern "C" {` in /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h, chain-included by many glibc header files. You could always check resulting post-processed code with `cpp` tool (C preprocessor, the same one used by gcc), btw